# How to declare an array with more than one type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function in which one of the arguments is an array that can have strings or numbers:

```
function functionName(argumentOne: string, argumentTwo: string, argumentThree: string[] | number[]) {
  ...
}
```

One instance of `argumentThree`: `["string1", 2, "string3"]`

`string[]` is an array of strings and `number[]` is an array of numbers. Therefore my code is giving me an error.

Comment: Array<string | number>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a union type for this:

```
//        alternatively: Array<string | number>
function myFunction(arr: (string | number)[]) {
  for (const element of arr) {
    // typeof element => string | number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this helps:**

```
function functionName(argumentOne: string, argumentTwo: string, argumentThree: Array<string | number>) {
  ...
}
```